# robots.txt disallow: spider

Tags: robots.txt, scraper

I'm looking at a [robots.txt file of a site I would like to do a one off scrape](http://www.rightmove.co.uk/robots.txt) and there is this line:

```
User-agent: spider

Disallow: /
```

Does this mean they don't want any spiders? I was under the impression that * was used for all spiders. If true this would of-course stop spiders such as google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just tells to agents that call themselves `spider` to be gently enough to not browse the site.

This has no special meaning.

robots.txt files are used only by robots, so a way to exclude all robots is to use a `*`:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: thanks, so its basically saying clearly identify your spider?